# Magento 2 - How to place dots vertically when the gallery is in fullscreen

Tags: magento2, gallery

When we click on the product image to zoom, I would like to show the dots vertically and not horizontally.
Has anyone done it or have any idea how it could be done?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_gallery.html#full_navdir

Comment: @Efran about dots, not thumbnails. Thx.